# Two interfaces recur inside each other

Tags: typescript

I declare two interfaces User and Customer as following:

```
export interface User {
  id: number,
  title: string,
  firstName: string,
  lastName: string,
  customer: Customer,
}

 export interface Customer {
  companyName: string,
  user: User,
}
```

when I create the initial value of these interfaces as following:

```
export const initialUser: User = {
  id: 0,
  title: '',
  firstName: '',
  lastName: '',
  customer: initialCustomer,
}

export const initialCustomer: Customer = {
  companyName: '',
  user: initialUser,
}
```

The error is: `can't access lexical declaration 'initialCustomer' before initialization.`

Comment: The [error](https://tsplay.dev/N73VDN)  I get with your code is slightly different but a little more descriptive... does this help you? If not, could you make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the error you're getting?

Comment: The only way I see this working is if user is optional on customer and you set user after you have created the object.

Comment: These sorts of circular dependency are a bit of a code-smell. Are you sure that this domain can't be modelled without circularity?

Comment: @RobertRendell I think I can use this approach at the moment.

Comment: Does [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgVQGc04BvAKDisQBMAuOJAVwFsAjNAGkupgRgA2wBoRhRkAc27U46BFFEA5TC2FxR4pFJ5UBmJSrUbJ06tiaiIqqAwDCFmFa7kAvuXKhIsRCjRZccPaW1mQ6cNhWYJhIAJ7KqiJiJmEWaAxEzm7uEUii4VDAmKgZUACCSDRBjta28uZ6UADybABWcAC8cAAUNEWYDACiINgCTDTAADwlnHAARObBaLMAfHAAZHBDI2OTVU5QMwDkqVCHywCUDKRwJ+nEB+EO+3ZPIS4dqxQyOXm3BPcdUIyGQIehwXowTAAOlBpmBcD4gjUEOhiKEcOBcgUMHiyL6UKxBlUGJkeiJeMhULJOMMJLMrzSjCYAgEcH0bNiGKy3wguXgC2qjL2IU61z+JxmERYUViuIYKKhUplcUMcDcMhS90VDKggIF+3cMgKMCYUCQZBu90lOrVriAA) works  for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in my comment:

```
export interface User {
  id: number,
  title: string,
  firstName: string,
  lastName: string,
  customer: Customer,
}

 export interface Customer {
  companyName: string,
  user?: User,
}

export const initialCustomer: Customer = {
  companyName: '',
}

export const initialUser: User = {
  id: 0,
  title: '',
  firstName: '',
  lastName: '',
  customer: initialCustomer,
}

initialCustomer.user = initialUser;
```

Comment: Note that this changes the `user` property on `Customer` to an [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) type, which was not mentioned in the question or [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75985036/two-interfaces-recur-inside-each-other/75985408#comment134016253_75985036).

Comment: it was mentioned in the comment, thanks for double checking though

Answer (score 0):

You can create them in an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) using a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) and return them in an object, then export each destructured value like this:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgVQGc04BvAKDkQBMAuOJAVwFsAjNAbkrhgRgBtg9QjCjIA5lyroEUEQDlMzIXBFikk7v0wKlKtRKlxsjERGVR6AYVMxzncgF9y5UJFiIUaLLjg2zFmTc2OZgmEgAnorKwqKG3KZo9EQOzq7g0PAhSCJwANrIfAiY-ClQADSeRSX+dhYAunAAvHAAFK0AlM0AfEFU2bmJlgTEUM19VDT0AAzl3FS8AioARMtzk3AycjDRK2vzcNq6MXCr65MmAUlkxqHhUXr0q3COcDp+tvYV3I5cCaMAOkudTQAKG4yGRigwBgjCgSHyQ0qQyBnwaXEcHU6XCAA)

```ts
export const [initialUser, initialCustomer] = (() => {
  const user: User = {
    id: 0,
    title: "",
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    customer: { companyName: "" } as Customer,
  };

  user.customer.user = user;
  return [user, user.customer];
})();
```

This will ensure that the linking is atomic in the scope outside the function.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using `as` in `{ companyName: "" } as Customer` this is skipping type checking and only really gets used for situations with `document.getElementById`, hence why TypeScript use it as the first example: shorturl.at/xFIY6. Nice use of closure though!